# Parse value from button to input through javascript.(toogle Popup Window)

Tags: javascript, popup

NEVER MIND PROBLEM SOLVED! THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

I have the following problem :

I have made a popup div section which is actually an image manager launcher, the thing is that I want when a person clicks on the image, the path of the image go to the input field.

But because there are lots of diferent albums with images inside, I am using the function .load() in Javascript to auto change the menu items.

Example

```
function changeDiv(link)
    {           
        if(link == 'album_cover'){          
            $('#images').load('image_manager.php?path=Album_cover'); 
        }
        if(link == 'background'){           
            $('#images').load('image_manager.php?path=Background'); 
        }
             .
             .more ifs
             .
}
```

I am in the post news area(link : post_new.php), the image_manager.php is for showing the images for each album. I am getting the path from the javascript and then I am showing the proper pictures.

I am using this function to pop up the window :

```
function toggleImageLauncher(x) {
        if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
            $('#'+x).fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $('#'+x).fadeOut(200);
        }
}
```

And some css too.

My problem now is : 
In image_manager.php have every single picture that is in the folder and in a table in my database too.

The code I have in echo at image_manager.php is :

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px;">

<input type="image"src="../media/siteAlbum_thumbs/'.$image['folder_name'].'/'.$image['title'].'"
onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(\'banner_image_link\').value='.$image['path'].'>

</div>
```

which is in a foreach getting every image's info from the database. $image is an array that have all the info of the image.

In post_new.php now I have the input :

```
Banner Image :
<input name="banner_image_link" type="text" size="50" maxlength="32" 
value="">

<input name="banner_image" type="button" value="Browse..." 
onClick="javascript:toggleImageLauncher('image_manager');">
```

Below that I have the album menu that apears in the popup window:

```
<div style="float:left;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="album" onclick="changeDiv('album_cover')">Album Cover</a></li>
                    <li><a id="back" onclick="changeDiv('background')">Background</a></li>
                    ... more <li></li>
                </div>
```

And after that I have the image div that calls the image_manager.php and shows all the pictures :

```
    <div id="images">

    </div>
```

I can't parse the value of the image path when I am clicking the image to the input with the name : banner_image_link.

For any more info please do not hessitate to ask me.

Thank you for your time and I am sorry for my big content!

Kind Regards,

Kostantinos Siaterlis

Comment: If you have find the solution, please choose the correct answer or post your answer to the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood you correctly..You click on an Image and than you want to read the src attribute of that image and copy that value into another input field  ?

Try this.

```
$('#imageID').live('click', function(){
   var src = $( this ).attr('src');
   $('#inputID').attr('value', src);
})
```

Comment: Yes i want to click an image and put the image src to an inptut text.
The thing is that the show image function is on an other file and i dont know how to parse the value from that file to my input.
I will try your solution tho :D Thanks alot!

Comment: youre welcome!So you want to send data(the path) from a.php to b.php ?